# Anagram of strings of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, anagram

This program is working for a single word but I want to pass an array of strings(more than one word).

```
let output = getAnagrams("CATCH"); //it is working for this

let output = getAnagrams(["catch", "Priest", "Monkey", "Bruise"]);
```

I want it to work for this.

```
function swap(chars, i, j) {
    var tmp = chars[i];
    chars[i] = chars[j];
    chars[j] = tmp;
}
function getAnagrams(input) {
    let newInput = input.toString().toLowerCase();
    console.log(newInput);
    var counter = [],
        anagrams = [],
        chars = newInput.split(''),
        length = chars.length,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        counter[i] = 0;
    }

    anagrams.push(newInput);
    i = 0;
    while (i < length) {
        if (counter[i] < i) {
            swap(chars, i % 2 === 1 ? Counter[i] : 0, i);
            counter[i]++;
            i = 0;
            anagrams.push(chars.join(''));
        } else {
            counter[i] = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }
    // return anagrams;
}
```

Comment: If you really *tried a lot* then show us what you have tried. Also, read [ask] so you understand why your question is inappropriate.

Comment: Hey, i tried loops but that is not working as i am not sure where should i put it .

Comment: What is `swap` - it's in your code but not included in the question.

Comment: Your input is now an array of strings. [Loop over the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) and use your code on each element.

Comment: Jamiec  that's a function which i forgot to put it. but now i put it here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you already have a method which takes 1 string, why not just call it for each string in your array and then flatten the returning the array using `flatMap`

```js
function getAnagrams(input) {
    let newInput = input.toString().toLowerCase();
    var counter = [],
        anagrams = [],
        chars = newInput.split(''),
        length = chars.length,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        counter[i] = 0;
    }

    anagrams.push(newInput);
    i = 0;
    while (i < length) {
        if (counter[i] < i) {
            swap(chars, i % 2 === 1 ? counter[i] : 0, i);
            counter[i]++;
            i = 0;
            anagrams.push(chars.join(''));
        } else {
            counter[i] = 0;
            i++;
        }
    }
     return anagrams;
}

function swap(arr,i,j){
  const tmp = arr[i];
  arr[i] = arr[j]
  arr[j] = tmp
}

const result = ["catch", "Priest", "Monkey", "Bruise"].flatMap(i => getAnagrams(i))

console.log(result)
```